# How do I programmatically get a styled version of an image via imagecache in D7?

Tags: 7, media

I want to save locally to the server, a styled version of an image attached to a node. "Styled" as in  filtered through a custom image style that I have already configured. What is the correct function, I can't find it anywhere.

I have file_unmanaged_copy() of the original image working fine, I can't see how to retrieve a styled version.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[theme_image_style](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7). Imagecache is replaced by image style in Drupal 7.
Example:

```
print theme('image_style',array('style_name' => 'thumbnail', 'path' => 'path/to/image'));
```

Comment: I saw this one, and since it returns HTML, and I only wanted the image, I thought it wasn't the right one. If I need to use this and then extract the image from it, I can do that, although that sounds a little inelegant.

Answer (score 5):

[image_style_url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7) ended up being the closest match to what I was looking for. It doesn't include the full html markup for the image, so I didn't need to do any additional work to get to it.